# Preposition: in /with

Tags: prepositions

> His portrait of Shah Jahan was published in/with his essay.

Are both prepositions correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using "with" isn't wrong, but "in" seems better.

However it depends. So if the portrait is a page within the essay itself then "in" is definitely better. But you could also have a set where the set includes the essay and a separate portrait. In that case "with" would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but they mean different things. "With" in this context would mean that the portrait was published alongside or at the same time as the essay but was not part of the essay. "In" would mean that the portrait was part of the essay.

Comment: True - and personally, I have never heard of such a thing as a portrait being considered as part of an essay.  I have only ever known portraits to be accompaniments to essays - so I suspect "with" is more likely to be correct - but no doubt there are exceptions.

Comment: Would it be incorrect if I write that there were two portraits published in his essay on human physiognomy?